# Error ReCAPTCHA placeholder element must be empty

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Buenos Días:

Tengo un problema con el uso del recaptcha de google en wordpress. El error que se muestra es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buscando un poco en internet, me encuentro con esta URL "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" donde hay un código expuesto, debido a que el problema radica en que hay librerías que se llaman varias veces, pero qué haría con ese código y cómo lo controlo. La funcionalidad es del cms propiamente(Ajustes de configuración de los plugins de los formularios).

El error asumo que es porque el recaptcha se utiliza varias veces en una misma página, por ende se cargan las librerías del recaptcha varias veces,pero una vez más,no sabría cómo controlar la carga de estas librerías si el recaptcha se configura en settings, en los plugins de los formularios. A la persona que me pueda ayudar se lo agradecería inmensamente.

Saludos!!!

Comment: Entonces, ¿instalaste un plugin para utilizar ReCaptcha, cierto? ¿No incluiste la librería manualmente en alguna parte? ¿No tienes dos plugin que hagan lo mismo y por eso la librería se duplica? ¿Escribiste algún código en alguna parte para implementar ReCaptcha?

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por responder, no,no instalé otro plugin para agregar el recaptcha. En ajustes del plugin de formularios se configura el recaptcha(Ninja Forms), parece que es la versión del Ninja Forms, porque me devolví a la versión 3 del Ninja Forms y este problema se solucionó, pero al pasar el cambio a producción se volvió a presentar el problema.

Comment: Entonces puede que sea un problema propio de ese plugin. En ese caso tendrás que consultar el apartado `Soporte` del plugin y eventualmente plantear allí el problema que estás teniendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! :)